# Quick way to get data into Google Sheets from Plaid's Liabilities API?

Tags: api, google-sheets, add-on, plaid

I am looking to get balance, credit available, payment due, due dates and other credit card info from the banks to a google sheet - using Plaid's "Liabilities" API. I have started down the path of the "quickstart" (which may be quick for a specialized developer but for me... nevermind) and I'm wondering, before I go too deep into the weeds with figuring out how to code it, has anyone wrapped it all up into a quick and easy add-on for google sheets by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware of a very similar add-on for Google Sheets, using the Transactions API instead: https://github.com/hirefrank/plaid-txns-google-sheets. You could probably modify it slightly to achieve what you're going for.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I took a look at it and it's helped me understand a lot. It should go a long ways toward making it infinitely faster for me to put together what I need!